# Showing data in power Bi matrix as percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

In the matrix, I have this representation -

```
        X   Y   Z   TOTAL
A       3   4   6   13
B       6   44  55  105
C       0   4   8   12
TOTAL   9   52  69  130
```

I want to show this as the following -

```
    X   Y   Z
A   23% 31% 46%
B   6%  42% 52%
C   0%  33% 67%
```

example, for row A -  (X/Total)*100 , (Y/Total)*100 ,(Z/Total)*100.

How do i do it?

Thanks in advance for your hep !

Answer (score 1):

[image]    Select values field and show value as pecentage of row total